Languages with quantification over *formulas*?
The 4th page of this paper mentions:

A first-order language that contains “substitutional quantifiers” (with formulas as substituends) in addition to ordinary quantifiers turns out to be precisely the sort of “infinitary” language that we need

So, it seems to be describing a sort of extension of first-order logic where you can quantify over formulas (in addition to the normal quantification over elements of the “universe of discourse”), but little detail is provided.
What exactly is this language (or class of languages)? Does anyone know of a book or something that talks about this in more detail?

Second-order or higher-order logic.

It seems a way to "embed" axiom schema into object language; see example: $S$ is true iff $\forall p ( \text {if } S='p',  \text { then } p)$.

Well, second-order logic allows quantification over subsets, but it’s not clear to me that this is the same as quantification over formulas.  For example in ZFC, not every FOL formula defines a subset (it may define a proper class)

Maybe useful this post.

The thing you're looking for is called second-order propositional logic. The name is a bit misleading, in that you can have a version of this logic that includes first-order quantifiers too (and is therefore a proper predicate logic), but that's how we distinguish it from the kind of second-order logic that model theorists like to study, which quantifies over sets.

Thanks @Z.A.K. Do you happen to know of a resource (book, lecture notes online, etc.) that discusses 2nd order propositional logic with 1st-order quantifiers? What I’ve found so far deals only with the standard 2nd-order prop. logic (no 1st-order quantifiers). The Wikipedia article is very brief and links to a paper I don’t have access to.

@NikS: Alas, I don't know any (which is one reason why I posted a comment instead of an answer). Even the propositional case is extremely difficult to study, thanks to impredicativity, so this is a fairly underdeveloped subject. If you just need a deductive system to work in that logic, you can take the union of the 1st and 2nd order sequent systems, and everything should work out fine, but if you need to understand it at a deeper level, well, that's going to be hard :(

You can sort of do it anyway just using Godel Numbering.

The reference made in the statement is to the notion of substitutional quantification, which is radically distinct from objectual quantification.
Objectual quantification is the conception of quantification of basic logic that we all are familiar with: A variable bound by a quantifier ranges over a domain of objects (i.e., the universe of discourse) and formulas are evaluated according to the objectual semantics (as defined in model theory at length).
In contrast, substitutional semantics does not specify a universe of discourse in advance. Hence,  variables do not range over objects; they are actually placeholders for substituends. Substituends are linguistic expressions in the form of proper names that replace variables to compose sentences. The truth conditions for quantifiers are accordingly modified. Usually, $\Sigma$ and $\Pi$ are used to denote the substitutional existential and universal quantifiers, respectively, but I prefer $\widetilde{\exists}$ and $\widetilde{\forall}$ to signify their connections to their classical counterparts as well as not to overload $\Sigma$ and $\Pi$ further.
I wish to present a rough and ready description of the substitutional interpretation. I shall put aside such elements of rigour as quasi-quotation while doing this to maintain focus.
In the following modified definitions, $\mathcal{M}$ denotes a model, $\phi$ a formula, $x$ a variable, $\alpha$ an individual constant in the language and $\phi(\alpha/x)$ indicates the syntactic operation of uniformly substituting $\alpha$ for all occurrences of $x$ in the open formula $\phi(x)$:
$\mathcal{M}\vDash\widetilde{\exists}x\phi(x)\iff$ for some individual constant $\alpha,\mathcal{M}\vDash\phi(\alpha/x)$
$\mathcal{M}\vDash\widetilde{\forall}x\phi(x)\iff$ for every individual constant $\alpha,\mathcal{M}\vDash\phi(\alpha/x)$
and the rest of the definitions are kept as the usual ones are.
Let us illustrate the modus operandi of substitutional quantification in a context involving Pegasus, the stock example for non-denoting names
(empty names, i.e., denoting the non-existent). Suppose, in the language, we have the following sentences among others:

Pegasus is a winged horse.
There is a horse that causes a stream to spring from the earth with a blow of his hoof.

Then, the quantified formula
($\widetilde{\exists}x)(x$ is a horse $\wedge x$ causes a stream to spring from the earth)
is true, since the substitution instance holds in the language (though the name is non-denoting, as opposed to the objectual interpretation).
Thus, substitutional semantics yields substitution classes that consist of those linguistic expressions of grammatically legitimate syntactic categories.
Since the grammar of the language is the only constraint, substitution classes can be expanded to include predicates and sentences (therefore, propositions). So, when we have

Cantor contends that inconsistent multiplicities are absolutely infinite sets.

the statement

$(\widetilde{\exists}p)$(Cantor contends $p$).

is legitimate in substitutional quantification:
To follow up the topic, I recommend Gabriel Uzquiano's SEoP article "Quantifiers and Quantification".
